# Sklearn Lasso prediction ndarry output issue

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am trying to predict output using sklearn output but actual ndarray looks different from one from output of Lasso because of this I am not able to calculate error. Did I anything? I want Y_PRED should look same as Y_ACT.

```
Y_PRED:
[[-0.2345764   2.95901652 -0.49351205 ..., -0.4138885  -0.51545272
  -0.43058412]]
Y_ACT :
[[-0.72284503]
 [ 3.31750686]
 [-0.42046417]
 ...,
 [-0.75198836]
 [-0.80438594]]
```

Here is sample code:

```
  x_df = TR_SET_FEATURE
  y_df = TR_SET_TARGET
  for train_index, test_index in kf:
     x_train = x_df.iloc[train_index, :].values
     x_test = x_df.iloc[test_index, :].values

     y_train = y_df.iloc[train_index].values
     y_test = y_df.iloc[test_index].values

     regr = ElasticNet(alpha=a)
     regr.fit(x_train, y_train)
     y_pred = regr.predict(x_test)

     print "y_pred: " ,y_pred.shape()
     print "y_act: " ,y_test.shape()


     pred_error = y_pred - y_test
```

Output:
        y_pred:
      File "dataframe.py", line 700, in 
        print "y_pred: " ,y_pred.shape()

Comment: What is `Y_PRED.shape()` and `Y_ACT.shape()`?

Comment: Also, this question would benefit greatly from a minimal, complete, verifiable example that other readers, who might help you, could run and see the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: `.shape` is a field, not a method